# Split a line of text to remove all numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheets document, a whole chain of text has multiple links from my website’s sitemap. I would like to split each URL onto a new line (there is a date and time between the URLs), so I’d like to get all of the links on to their own lines.

This is just a sample as there will be a much longer chain of text, but is there a way to achieve this? I would like to try and use code or some form of splitting-text method so any explanation is welcome! The document is live and editable so if you’d like to experiment with a solution by all means try something on the sheet!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RRaJX96tsFZ3dyE5opUC6pSuPTreTb4IyjrLjPTEvA/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`=arrayformula(regexreplace(trim(transpose(split($B$3,"weekly",false))),"\ .*",))`

`SPLIT` function splits the text by the word 'weekly'. `false` ensures that the match is 'weekly', not 'w', 'e', 'k', 'l' or 'y'.

`TRANSPOSE` then lists the result in a column.

`TRIM` removes any leading spaces.

`REGEXREPLACE` gets rid of everything after (and including) the space '`\` '.

`ARRAYFORMULA` works down the column of values generated by the `TRANSPOSE`.

The formula can sit anywhere on the sheet, apart from cells B1:B3.